# there's a problem when I use npm to install something

Tags: javascript

when I first use webstorm,I want to install some modules with npm.But there's something I have no idea how to solve.the problem like this:
npm install express
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "_chalk@1.1.3@chalk": name cannot start with an underscore; name can only contain URL-friendly characters

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-11-20T02_48_31_052Z-debug.log
Thanks!

Comment: When you see "chalk..." INVALID...like this.You just deet a file named ".nmprc",and then you uninstall & install nodejs.It works out!

Answer (score 3):

Remove node_modules, package-lock.json and try to install chalk directly here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk/v/1.1.3

npm i chalk

Also, look at the error log at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-11-20T02_48_31_052Z-debug.log, that can help to see root issue.

Answer (score 1):

npm install chalk@1.1.3

Or

npm i chalk

Try this command......
If still get an error search for chalk folder in node modules and delete it then run these command again.

Comment: Thank u,I have solved it.It seems OK when I delete a file named".ncprm"(maybe,I forget how to spell but like this.).And then I install node again.It works well.

Comment: Ok @sun zheng. You can edit the answer and approve it

Comment: yeah,awesome!I'll do it.